# wget get download path but do not download

Tags: curl, wget

I have the following folder structure:

```
example.com
|
|_ folder1
| |_ file1.mp4
|
|_ folder2
| |_ file2.mp4
|
|_ folder3
| |_ file3.mp4
|
|_ folder4
  |_ file4.mp4
```

I would like to download all the mp4 files, which I can do with:

`wget --no-parent  -A mp4 example.com/`

However, the files are large in size and it will not all fit on my machine. So instead, I just want to get the `path` of each `mp4` and I can download when I have more space.

How can I get the following urls, and maybe output to a file (doesn't matter if url encoded or not):

```
example.com/folder1/file1.mp4
example.com/folder2/file2.mp4
...
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "get". You could download the files to /dev/null, or you could just get the HTTP headers with `curl --head -i /http://example.com...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make list of addresses utilizing wget:

```
# parse listing index.html 
$ wget -O- http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/lzip/ | grep -oE '["].*\.lz["]' | sed -e 's/^.*href=//' -e 's/\"//g' > urls.txt
# download files from list
$ wget -i urls.txt
```

If you have more of them you can put them in array and then

```
addresses=(\
"http://aaaaa" \
"http://bbbb" \
"http://ccc" \
)

for adr in ${addresses[@]}; do
    wget -O- ...
done
```

You can also combine all of it - make list of listings (index.html-s) in first step then list of .mp4-s in second and then download from that list with `wget -i <urls>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reject the mp4 files, while logging the rejections to a file that you can later use to download those mp4.

Based on your command above (you might want to add `-r`):

```
wget --no-parent --rejected-log=file.rej -R mp4 example.com/
```

The rejections will be in `file.rej`. It has many fields, the second one is the rejected URL.